# looking for a special type of node.js proxy module

Tags: node.js, proxy

i am just now digging into everything node.js related as i am tasked with a somewhat complex requirement. I need to implement a kind of a proxy service using node.js, i am not even sure it can be called a proxy per-se.

What i need is the following:

setup a web server that would listen to requests, then, query a database for a list of URLs (according to some data from the original request), curl these URLs and according to the responses from these URLs construct a response to the original client. The response would be some kind of mix and mash from these multiple responses according to some business logic.

So in short :
Client -> NODE -> NODE queries DB, calls N Urls, processes responses, construct response to client -> return response to client.

I've looked at node-http-proxy but it doesn't seem like a good match for what i need.

Basically i am looking at pointers of how can this be accomplished. Performance is of outmost importance as we'll be serving 50K-100K QPS or more.

Comment: These services already exist.  Do a search for API proxy services... there are many many out there that allow you to combine upstream responses and otherwise transform the data.  For your traffic load, I'd use something tried and true.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will find a module that will do the job for you. You have to write something completely custom. You can pick a framework like express, that will create the server and will handle the requests for you. Then pick the database driver that you need to connect to the database and use the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to fire the requests to the URLs that you will retrieve from the database. It can be a quite an overhead if you have to fire a lot of requests. [Async module](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.each) and specifically async.each will help you. This can fire all the requests in parallel and at the very last callback have the results in an array. Process the results, send them back to the client. It should not be quite complicated.